# How to enqueue wordpress styles from outside wp_content

Tags: wordpress, styles

The usual way of enqueueing would be to use

```
wp_enqueue_styles('style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/bundle.css', array(), '', true);
```

to enqueue `bundle.css` from the root of the theme dir. However, my theme dir is outside of `wp-content` to support bundling the php files with scss and js and still keeping src and dist directory separated.

Under normal circumstances `get_template_directory_uri()` returns something like `/wp-content/themes/...` and `wp_enqueue_styles` generates `<link href="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/...`

But when using `register_theme_dir` to load a theme from outside of `wp_content` I get `<link href="http://localhostC:\projects\...`, of course, WordPress can't generate a link that can be served from the webserver because my folder is not in htdocs, but WordPress still appends the host to the local file system path with doesn't make any sense.

Is there any way of telling wp_enqueue_styles to use the path I pass verbatim and don't append the host?

When enqueueing style from another server with

```
wp_enqueue_styles('style', 'https://cdn.js...', array(), '', true);
```

it also doesn't append my host, so I tried using a `file:///` but that didn't work either.

Note that this is only for local development so it's fine to specify resources outside htdocs, when uploading to prod everything gets packaged in zip and is uploaded the normal wp-content dir.

Answer (score 0):

replace `get_template_directory_uri()` with `home_url()` - It gives you the root url and then you can just manually type in URL to your file.